# What does “$d$-generated algebra” mean?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-superalgebras

I would like to know what does ”$d$-generated algebra” mean? In particular “two-generated algebra”?

---

@KonstantinosKanakoglou @LSpice
Here is an example of a paper concerning “one-generated algebras”:  [Camacho, Karimjanov, Kaygorodov, and Khudoyberdiyev - One-generated nilpotent Novikov algebras](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340523382_One-generated_nilpotent_Novikov_algebras); but I would like to know what does “$d$-generated algebra” mean in general, and what is the difference between “$d$-generated” and “$d$-dimensional”.

Comment: It would help if you add some reference to clarify the context. For example, where have you found this term?

Comment: is it specific to lie superalgebras ?

Comment: As @KonstantinosKanakoglou suggests, it's impossible to answer this without background, but an obvious guess is a Lie algebra that has a generating set containing $d$ elements.

Comment: Your example [Camacho, Karimjanov, Kaygorodov, and Khudoyberdiyev - One-generated nilpotent Novikov algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.03598) seems to suggest my [guess](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/411976/what-does-d-generated-algebra-mean#comment1055667_411976):  a $d$-generated algebra is an algebra that can be generated by $d$ elements (and perhaps by no fewer elements?).  A $d$-generated vector space is thus a $\le d$-dimensional vector space; but it need not be so for algebras because the algebra generated by a set is usually bigger than the vector space generated by the set.

Comment: This makes sense for every universal algebra structure, or even structure including partially defined laws (e.g. fields), i.e., the algebra for which there is a subset of cardinal $\le d$ such that the only substructure (= stable under all the given laws) is the whole algebra.

Comment: An algebra is $d$-generated if $d$ is the smallest integer such that there exist $d$ elements whose iterated products, however associated, span the algebra. The only Lie algebra that is $1$-generated in this sense is the trivial one-dimensional Lie algebra. For example, $sl(2)$ is $2$-generated in this sense although it is $3$-dimensional. M. Kuranishi showed that over a field of characteristic $0$ any semisimple Lie algebra is $2$-generated (https://doi.org/10.1017/S0027763000010059).

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou  thank you very much for your answers and your clarifications.

Comment: @LSpice   thank you very much for your answers and your clarifications.

Comment: @YCor thank you very much for your answers and your clarifications.

Comment: @DanFox thank you very much for your answers and your clarifications.